# Call to a member function hasTranslation() on null - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-translatable

I am using Laravel Translatables. But when I execute I got an error like `Call to a member function hasTranslation() on null`. Here is my code.

```
<?php 
    if($slider->product->hasTranslation($locale))
    {
       $type = $slider->product->translate($locale)->product_name;
    }
    else{
       $type = $slider->product->translate('en')->product_name;
    } //echo $type; exit;

?>
```

`$slider->product` is not null and `$locale` has value `'en'`
This code is working fine yesterday, the only change I made is, from the admin panel I just removed the required validation from add product field.

Comment: Is your model setup correct? Does it use the trait? Are you sure `$slider->product` is not null?

Comment: @kerbholz for some products `$slider->product` is empty because it is not a mandatory field. So what modifications needed in my code. I am new to laravel

Answer (score 2):

Check the setup of your relation `$slider->product` is not null

and the model has `use Translatable` trait

there is a helper method called optional()

```
optional($slider->product)->hasTranslation($locale)
```

this method will avoid to throw an exception.

> NOT RECOMMENDED TO USE IT (optional()) IF $slider->product MUST HAVE A VALUE

just shortcut for clean code

```
if(optional($slider->product)->hasTranslation($locale))
   $type = optional($slider->product)->translate($locale)->product_name;
else
   $type = optional($slider->product)->translate('en')->product_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with another `if` condition. Modified code is

```
<?php if(!empty($slider->product)) {

        if($slider->product->hasTranslation($locale))
        {
          $type = $slider->product->translate($locale)->product_name;
        }
        else{
          $type = $slider->product->translate('en')->product_name;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: this not logic. you can instead of this many if ( optional() ) method that i provided

Comment: see last line of my answer